# Cordova / Ionic Framework deploy: Prevent from falling back to emulator

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I've setup a small build and deploy server on a shared Mac which remotely checks out an ionic project, builds it and deploys it to a plugged iOS device.

```
ionic run ios --device
```

That works fine, but if someone forgets to plugin the iOS device, OSX falls back to running an emulator. This is annoying as it pulls a lot of resources and you have to actually close it physically on the Mac yourself.

Is there a way to PREVENT Cordova, Ionic, OSX, Xcode from starting the emulator if there's no real device plugged in?

Comment: file a feature request on issues.cordova.io